# Finding values of a binary operation defined on N.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> We are given an operation $*$ on the natural numbers, satisfying
> (i) $1*n=n+1$ for all $n$
> (ii) $m*1=(m-1)*2$ for all $m>1$
> (iii) $m*n=(m-1)*(m*(n-1))$ for all $m,n>1$.
> Find the value of $5*5$.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1i8E.png) is a table I got, where $m*n$ is at the intersection of row $m$
and column $n$.

The way I worked it out is row by row, using $m*n$ to get $m*(n+1)$ through the identity $$m*(n+1)=(m-1)*(m*n)$$ e.g. $$2*1=1*2=3$$ and $$2*(n+1)=1*(2*n)$$ gives us the second row, etc.
I had to conjecture the formulae $3*n=2n+2$ and $4*n=2^{n+2}-2$ which I think could be shown by induction (if correct). However the value I get for $5*5=2^{2^{2^{2^{16}}}}-2$ seems too ridiculous to be correct, and in general there must be a simpler way of solving the question.

Comment: Aside: MathJax/LaTeX is really good at formatting arrays and tables and matrices and the like - you don't need external links. Google for "latex array environment" for more information.

Comment: I withdraw my earlier daft comment about solving this: naively rewriting with the recursion equations isn't computationally feasible in this case. Recursion equations like this can show very fast growth rates, so I would advise you to try to prove your conjectures for the values of $3 * n$ and $4 * n$.

Comment: Your function is very like the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), which does indeed have a remarkably fast growth rate. I think $2$ in formula (ii) may be a typo: as things stand your table does't agree with the formulas (the formulas give $2 * 2 = 3$  not $4$).

Comment: Thanks! I think it's exactly the Ackermann function, with the inputs (and thus the outputs) translated.  As for your other comment $2*2=1*(2*1)=1*3=4$ seems right to me.

Comment: Looking through the wikipedia page my table and answer look right to me (taking into account the translation).

Comment: You're right. Apologies for the red herring.